# volatile is a storage specifier or storage class in c?

Tags: c, declaration

What is the difference between *storage class* and *storage specifier* in C ? Is volatile a *storage class* or *storage specifier*?

EX: `static volatile int a;` 
    taking without any error but
    `static auto/register/extern int a;` is giving compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

The following are storage class specifiers and there can be at most one:

```
typedef
extern
static
auto
register
```

we can see this from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.1` *Storage-class specifiers*, which lists the above specifiers and says:

> At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration.102)

`volatile` on the other hand is a *type qualifier* which we can see from section `6.7.3` *Type qualifiers* which lists the following qualifiers:

```
const
restrict
volatile
```

and also says:

> If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same
>   specifier-qualifier-list, either directly or via one or more typedefs,
>   the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

We can see from the grammar in section `6.7` *Declarations* that a declaration can have both a *storage class specifier* and a *type qualifier*:

```
declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
```